# Find a script which can stop shut down Azure Vm from azure portal when the Vm is restarting after the patch applied

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, virtual-machine, azure-automation

Background:

Now I use an Azure Automation to shutdown the Azure Vms,

but I met a problem last time when one VM had been shutdown form the Azure portal

when it was restarting after the applied patch and the result was the VM could not start again.

I want to find if there has a script that can check if the VM is restart/start/shutdown when I shut down the VM from Azure Portal.
Thanks in ad

Comment: Read the tag associated with your Q [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure). Voting to close, StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Automation to schedule all your Start/Stop/Restart jobs. If ever, you need to check when and how your VMs have been restarted and by whom, you could check the Log history from the portal, inside your VM's sections. To automate the display of this using a script, you could use a simple runbook that queries the tables from the access logs of your VM, and triggers an action of your choice...

I hope this could help you resolve your issue :)